# Public directory of angularjs directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Where are some public listings of angularjs directives that people have written?  FYI I'm obviously not asking about directives that are included with angularjs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Public listing of angularjs directives: http://ngmodules.org/

Another great resource for angular equivalent of JQuery UI: http://angular-ui.github.io/

For bootstrap lovers: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: Are there any other big ng directive listings?

Comment: Those are the ones I am aware of. There may be others.